# How to sum every two rows of a csr matrix fast?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large scipy csr matrix (250k, 2.5M), and want to sum every two rows in it very fast (keeping the same number of columns, so final shape (125k, 2.5M)). Actually, the problem is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428193/summing-blocks-of-n-rows-in-numpy-array), but I can't convert my matrix to a dense array because of RAM.

The approaches I've written so far iterating over rows are way too slow, is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How do you create this matrix?  It might be easier to do this sum before or during the setup.

Comment: @hpaulj currently, in simulations, I assemble it from individual rows using scipy.sparse.vstack, but to be useful in intended applications, a csr matrix would be given as a whole, so looking for a solution that would operate on the final matrix directly.

Comment: `vstack` uses `bmat` which combines the `coo` attributes of the individual arrays.

Comment: Sparse is good at matrix multiplication.  Can you make a sparse matrix to do the jkb?  e.g. `[[1 1 0 0 ...] [0 0 1 1 0 ...]...]`

Answer (score 1):

A small example using matrix multiplication:

The matrix to sum:

```
In [15]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))
```

A summation matrix:

```
In [16]: A = sparse.csr_matrix([[1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1]])

In [17]: M
Out[17]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>    
In [18]: M.A
Out[18]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]], dtype=int32)

In [19]: A
Out[19]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>    
In [20]: A.A
Out[20]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

The multiplication:

```
In [21]: A@M
Out[21]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>    
In [22]: (A@M).A
Out[22]: 
array([[ 3,  5,  7],
       [15, 17, 19]], dtype=int32)
```

All the rows are summed with a similar multiplication:

```
In [23]: np.array([1,1,1,1])@M
Out[23]: array([18, 22, 26], dtype=int32)
In [24]: M.sum(axis=0)
Out[24]: matrix([[18, 22, 26]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index array for the odd and even row, then split the sparse matrix to two matrixes, then do the addition.

Here is an exemple :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
arr_numpy = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
array_sum_numpy = arr_numpy.reshape(-1,2,arr_numpy.shape[-1]).sum(1)
arr_sparse = csr_matrix(arr_numpy)
index_odd = np.arange(1, arr_sparse.shape[0], 2)
index_even = np.arange(0, arr_sparse.shape[0], 2)
arr_sparse_odd= arr_sparse[index_odd]
arr_sparse_even = arr_sparse[index_even]
array_sum_sparse = arr_sparse_odd + arr_sparse_even
print(np.array_equal(array_sum_numpy, array_sum_sparse.toarray()))
```

Which gives you the result :

> True

That means two arrays are the same.

Then if we try with your case with defining a function :

```
def sparse_addition(arr_sparse):
    index_odd = np.arange(1, arr_sparse.shape[0], 2)
    index_even = np.arange(0, arr_sparse.shape[0], 2)
    arr_sparse_odd= arr_sparse[index_odd]
    arr_sparse_even = arr_sparse[index_even]
    array_sum_sparse = arr_sparse_odd + arr_sparse_even
    return array_sum_sparse

import scipy.sparse as sps
rows, cols = 250*1000, int(2.5*1e6)
# Initialization
arr_sparse = csr_matrix((rows, cols))
# Fill values in the sparse matrix
for j in np.arange(10): 
    r = np.random.randint(rows, size=1000000)
    c = np.random.randint(cols, size=1000000)
    d = np.ones((1000000,))
    arr_sparse = arr_sparse + sps.coo_matrix((d, (r, c)), shape=(rows, cols))

arr_sparse
```

> <250000x2500000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'   with
> 9999915 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Then we check the executing time and the shape:

```
%timeit arr = sparse_addition(arr_sparse)
```

> 132 ms ± 4.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
arr.shape
```

> (125000, 2500000)

Comment: `arr_sparse[index_odd]`  indexing like this uses matrix multiplication.  It converts makes a sparse 'extractor' matrix from the `index_odd`.  Row and column summation is also dones with matrix multiplication (but with simple dense matrices).